# Function read argument or stdin

Tags: bash, function, awk, stdin

I 
[noticed that](http://github.com/git/git/blob/41ccfdd/git-add--interactive.perl#L1147)
with Perl’s `print`, you can print from a string or from `STDIN`. I have a simple function that can work from a string

```
warn ()
{
  awk '{printf "\033[36m%s\033[m\n", $0}' <<< $1
}
```

or from `STDIN`

```
warn ()
{
  awk '{printf "\033[36m%s\033[m\n", $0}'
}
```

However can I modify the function such that it could accept either like Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
warn () {
  ( if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then exec <<< $1
    fi
    awk '{printf "\033[36m%s\033[m\n", $0}'
  )
}
```

The `exec` command allows you to perform a redirection that persists to following commands.

Comment: I found I needed to wrap this with `exec 3<&0 [...] exec <&3`

Comment: You shouldn't need that, the `(...)` executes the code in a subshell so that redirections are undone automatically.

Comment: If the whole function runs in a subshell, you can remove the braces -- `warn() ( ... )` -- see [Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual